# Hiding NA's when printing a dataframe in apa_table (papaja)

Tags: r, na, kable, papaja

I am trying to print a table with apa_table (papaja) using `options(knitr.kable.NA = "")`. Whatever I try the NAs are still printed.

I tried with kable which worked just fine. But I need to use apa_Table. Is there a workaround or any idea why it doesn't work?

Sample code in my header:

```
    options(knitr.kable.NA = '')
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**papaja** has its own option `papaja.na_string` to specify which character is to be printed if NAs occur.

For instance, you may specify

```
options(papaja.na_string = "")
```

to suppress the printing of NAs in tables (but also in text).